# GMLib 1.5.3 InfoWindow issue of GMPolygon

Tags: infowindow, gmlib

Since the 16th of may, my InfoWindows of my GMPolygons pop up in the middle of the Atlantic Ocean (rLat = 0, rLng = 0). I understand now this has to do with the experimental version of Google Maps Api (now v3.28, 3 days ago v3.27). How can i use GMLib 1.5.3 with the released version 3.27 ?

Comment: how do you uses the InfoWindows? Can you put some code example?

Comment: It is not so excited this code:
  Trjct.Polygon1 := TPolygon(GMPolygon1.Add);
  Trjct.Polygon1.StrokeColor := clBlack;
  Trjct.Polygon1.StrokeOpacity := 0.9;
  Trjct.Polygon1.StrokeWeight := 1;
  Trjct.Polygon1.FillColor := clYellow;
  Trjct.Polygon1.FillOpacity := 0.2;
  Trjct.Polygon1.Text := 'T' + Format('%.*d',[2, nr1]) + Format('%.*d',[2, nr2]) + ' ' + WegNr;
  Trjct.Polygon1.InfoWindow.HTMLContent := Trjct.Polygon1.Text;

Comment: @cadetill the problem since a few days is, that if you click on the polygon, the infowindow doesn't show up at the right spot (at the beginning of the polygon) but somewhere in the Atlantic Ocean

Comment: Thank you @cadetill . I have installed version 1.5.5 and this issue (and other issues) about TLatLng were gone. Great software mate !!!